# How to replace value between xml tags using regex in Ant?

Tags: regex, xml, ant

I'm trying to use Ant for replacing value in xml.

My xml file:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I want to replace `60` to `20`

And use for this following regexp in ant task `replaceregexp`:

```
(?<=session-timeout>)[\S\s]*?(?=</session-timeout)


<target name="step1">
        <replaceregexp file="WEB-INF/web.xml"
                       byline="true"
                       match="((?<=session-timeout\>)[\S\s]*?(?=\<\/session-timeout))"
                       replace='20'/>
</target>
```

But got fatal error from ant after execution:

```
[Fatal Error] The value of attribute "match" associated with an element type "replaceregexp"
 must not contain the '<' character.
```

Please advise, how to change my regexp, or maybe there is an another solution of this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<` and `>` characters must be "escaped" by using `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

```
<replaceregexp file="WEB-INF/web.xml"
              byline="true"
              match="((?&lt;=session-timeout\&gt;)[\S\s]*?(?=\&lt;\/session-timeout))"
              replace='20'/>
```